# Passing parameters to exe. file from SSIS

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis, etl, executeprocesstask

Currently, I'm trying to call a python exe. file and pass the parameters to it from an SSIS package. When I run the package from Visual Studio it does it intended purpose, but when I deploy it to the database although its running nothing happens.

[image: SSIS PACKAGE]

The exe file only opens a command prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Trying to figure out the issue

Since you specified the full file path in the Executable property, you don't have to pass any value in the working directory property (leave it empty) or remove the following string from executable property:

```
E:\BOJ\PrimeBOJReport\generatePrimeReportMain
```

In addition, check the the SQL user running the package has a permission to access the path specified and since you are executing cmd check that you are not using a SQL Service account because it may be unable to execute cmd correctly. Try using Windows login instead.

Comment: The issue is when I'm running the package from SQL Server its not passing the parameters to the executable, therefore, the API isn't being called and the data is not inserted to the table

Comment: @DavidSmith i didn't mention anything about parameters.

Comment: I know, what I'm saying is when the package is deployed it runs successfully but it does nothing, so I'm assuming the parameters isn't being passed to the executable. The executable takes two parameters, plus the command prompt as showed in the second picture doesn't appare either

Comment: @DavidSmith what is the user used to execute the package?

Comment: @DavidSmith try executing package using a windows login not sql or service account